# How to add a polyline overlay to a static image in Mapbox?

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm trying to save a map with a route as a static image. I'm currently able to save the map as a static map with some annotations as overlay, but I'm unable to figure out how to add the route to the static map.

This is the code I currently have:

```
List<StaticMarkerAnnotation> markers = new ArrayList<>();
List<StaticPolylineAnnotation> polylines = new ArrayList<>();

markers.add(StaticMarkerAnnotation.builder().name(StaticMapCriteria.LARGE_PIN)
             .lnglat(Point.fromLngLat(pointList.getFirst().longitude(), pointList.getFirst().latitude()))
             .label("a")
             .build());

markers.add(StaticMarkerAnnotation.builder().name(StaticMapCriteria.LARGE_PIN)
             .lnglat(Point.fromLngLat(pointList.getLast().longitude(),pointList.getLast().latitude()))
             .label("b")
             .build());

polylines.add(StaticPolylineAnnotation.builder().polyline(currentRoute.geometry()).build()); // DirectionsRoute currentRoute

String staticImage = MapboxStaticMap.builder()
             .accessToken(getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token))
             .width(mapView.getMeasuredWidth())
             .height((int) (250*getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density))
             .retina(true)
             .cameraAuto(true)
             .staticMarkerAnnotations(markers)
             .staticPolylineAnnotations(polylines) // does not work!
             .build()
             .url()
             .toString();
```

Without the .staticPolylineAnnotations(polylines) it creates successfully creates a static image (without route). With the .staticPolylineAnnotations(polylines), the created staticImage string results in {"message":"Latitude must be between -85.0511-85.0511."}.

I guess I'm passing my currentRoute incorrectly, but I don't know the right way.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the Route image in Android First add your all Lat and Long into a List and after that convert your complete list of lat and long into encoded poly line string with the help of Google Poly line Encoding techniques.

-> After that create Map box account and use static image API of map box with valid token

-> Now use StaticPolylineAnnotation:

List{StaticPolylineAnnotation} list1 = new ArrayList<>();
(Replace {} with <>) list.add(StaticPolylineAnnotation.builder().polyline(polilineString).strokeWidth(1.0).strokeColor(56, 69, 181).build()); Note: PolilineString is your encoded string got from Google Poly line Encoding techniques

-> MapboxStaticMap staticImage = MapboxStaticMap.builder().user("mapboxaccountusename") .accessToken("Mapbox Token") .styleId("Your Style id") .staticPolylineAnnotations(list1) .cameraAuto(true) .retina(true) .build();

->get url of image using String imageUrl = staticImage.url().toString();

Answer (score 0):

This error message {"message": "Latitude must be between -85.0511-85.0511."} usually appears when you have the latitude and longitude in a reversed order. It worth testing your coordinates in the [Mapbox direction API playground](https://docs.mapbox.com/playground/directions/) to validate it before adding them to your implementation.

You could also explore using the [MapSnapshotter for Android](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/snapshotter/) to save your map with a route.